# Problems installing Ruby on Mountain Lion - ruby 1.9.3 wont' compile

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I have seen a number of posts on this before and have followed their instructions but nothing is working. I'll outline below what I have done, and the instructions I have follows - would be grateful for any advice!

I have followed the following installation instructions: 
http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac

I have downloaded X-code for OSX Mountain Lion, and installed the gcc compiler:

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I have then done as instructed and installed the latest version of git

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)
```

and similarly done the same with rvm via command line:

```
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.16.13 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

When I then try to install ruby using RVM, I get the following:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p286.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracted to /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mondemoo/.rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mondemoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286', please read /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Using the alternate command line I get a similar output though the with some extra bits:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
-bash: -dumpversion: command not found
-bash: --version: command not found
-bash: --version: command not found
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracted to /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mondemoo/.rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mondemoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286 --with-gcc=clang', please read /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
-bash: --version: command not found
```

Looking into the configure.logs, I get the following:

```
$ less /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/configure.log
[2012-10-17 07:39:15] env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mondemoo/.rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mondemoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286 --with-gcc=clang
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/mondemoo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I'm now utterly confused as to what I have done wrong - is anyone able to assist?? It appears that there is an issue with the c-compiler (gcc?), am I interpreting it correctly?  If so how do I fix that? Also how do I get to this "config.log" that is mentioned in the configure.log above?

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your post using four-space indentation for terminal output.

Comment: So what does the configure log say?

Comment: please read /Users/mondemoo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/configure.log , it's polite about it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan just found out how to indent :-)  Half-elf& Warren, I've just added in the contents of the configure.log file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bug in RailsInstaller OSX 1.0.3 - https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix/issues/10

you need to change `/etc/rvmrc` to contain this:

```
umask g+w
export -a rvm_configure_env
rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

I will prepare new version of the installer when binary ruby is available for 2.0.0.

UPDATE: for new version of RVM `1.19+` `/etc/rvmrc` should be changed to:

```
umask g+w
export rvm_autolibs_flag=smf
```

And run `rvm get stabel #OR: head`

Comment: Ignore my last post, just saw the line continues - will try it now.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked for me... and to install Ruby 2.0.0 too.

Comment: so now is April 11, 2013 and this is still not fixed.  Why do Rails always have issues and I google for error messages the most in my life for Rails installation or setup issues

Comment: I did a `more /etc/rvmrc` and there is no such file.  That's great

Comment: updating rvm should either fix it or show you how to fix it, this problem occurs on your system, it can not be automatically fixed remotely - you need to take action to fix it ... most important read the outputs of the commands you run

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I did it the 'correct' way, but I just removed RVM (rvm implode) and then reinstalled it (\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby) and it installed and is now running the latest version of ruby 1.9.3-p327 no problem.

Comment: I actually got this to work again too, however I'm still having other issues building other things that require native extensions.  :(