# The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rubygems

I recently upgraded to OS Mountain Lion. A project I'm working on requires gem sys-proctable as a dependency, but when I run `bundle install` I get:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
.
.
.
Installing sys-proctable (0.9.2) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_pid_t in ruby.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1022:in `try_type'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in have_type'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1049:in `have_type'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-darwin for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-darwin/ext/darwin/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sys-proctable (0.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sys-proctable -v '0.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

But I do have developer tools installed! Running `gem install sys-proctable -v '0.9.2'` gives me nearly the same error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sys-proctable:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_pid_t in ruby.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1022:in `try_type'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in have_type'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1049:in `have_type'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-darwin for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-darwin/ext/darwin/gem_make.out
[sample_app(filling-in-layout)]$ /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
                                                                              A [sample_app(filling-in-layout)]$ gem install sys-proctable -v '0.9.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sys-proctable:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_pid_t in ruby.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1022:in `try_type'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in have_type'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1049:in `have_type'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-darwin for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-darwin/ext/darwin/gem_make.out
```

Here's the content of my `mkmf.log` file:

```
"/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0 -I/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Now I recently reinstalled XCode and Command Line Tools, but I'm worried that I somehow fucked up my C compiler, because when I try to run `rvm --force install 1.9.3` I get the following errors:

```
No binary rubies available for: downloads/ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
lipo: can't open input file:  (No such file or directory)
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
Configuring yaml in /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
Patch cflags was already applied.
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --with-gcc=clang', please read /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Contents of `configure.log`

```
[2012-11-07 18:02:12] env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --with-gcc=clang
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Finally, contents of `config.log`:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --with-gcc=clang

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Mattans-MacBook-Air.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.2.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 138 tasks, 703 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 3.07, Mach factor: 1.53
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/sm/bin
PATH: /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
PATH: /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2788: checking build system type
configure:2802: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
configure:2870: checking host system type
configure:2883: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
configure:2903: checking target system type
configure:2916: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
configure:3395: checking for C compiler version
configure:3404: clang --version >&5
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
configure:3415: $? = 0
configure:3404: clang -v >&5
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
configure:3415: $? = 0
configure:3404: clang -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:3415: $? = 1
configure:3404: clang -qversion >&5
clang: error: no input files
configure:3415: $? = 1
configure:3435: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3457: clang   -L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/lib conftest.c  >&5
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include'
configure:3461: $? = 1
configure:3499: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3504: error: in `/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194':
configure:3506: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/lib'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
ac_cv_prog_CC=clang
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='ruby'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='clang'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS='-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/lib'
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2012-04-20'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin12.2.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin12.2.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin12.2.0'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in RailsInstaller OSX 1.0.3 - (Found that out while reading [Problems installing Ruby on Mountain Lion - ruby 1.9.3 wont' compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928581/problems-installing-ruby-on-mountain-lion-ruby-1-9-3-wont-compile))

I needed to change `/etc/rvmrc` to contain this:

```
umask g+w
export -a rvm_configure_env
rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

For more info see: https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix/issues/10

Answer (score 24):

Same problem occurred and I finally solved it. 
Here are the steps I followed:

- Xcode, Xcode CLT
- `sudo xcodebuild -license`
- `sudo port upgrade outdated`
- `sudo port install apple-gcc42`
- `rvm reinstall 1.9.3` **#important!**

Really, I think just first,second and last steps required, but can not test it.

Comment: everytime I try rvm reinstall 1.9.3 I get the same error: `Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log
`

Comment: I had to run that with sudo in order for it to execute correctly. You may want to try that.  :)

Comment: For future visitors, this worked for me. Not that it should matter but I installed rvm with brew. Xcode and Xcode CLT was already installed. I simply had to (no sudo throughout any of this) `rvm use 2.0.0`, then `xcode -license`, agree to the license then `rvm reinstall 2.0.0`. last step very important, indeed

Comment: I use `rbenv`. Doing `sudo xcodebuild -license` and agreeing to the license did the job.

Answer (score 20):

Be sure to open XCode after updates. I found that I had to open it and accept the new license agreement after a recent update of XCode via the App Store. Otherwise I received the "The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first."

Comment: This worked for me, and I hadn't seen it recommended in any of the other threads around gem / ruby / xcode issues.

Comment: After a new update of Xcode, I found I had to run the app to 1) Accept the Agreement and then 2) for the app to install all of its components.

Comment: Was going crazy with this issue, especially with some of the proposed solutions on this post and others, I updated xcode last night and didn't open the app, worked like a charm, thanks

Comment: Worked for me. For information, no need to run XCode, just run in your terminal `sudo xcodebuild -license`, it will allow you to accept the new licences.

Answer (score 14):

The following steps resolved the issue.

1. `xcode-select --install`
2. `sudo xcodebuild -license`

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: It works for me, indeed, it works only with `xcode-select --install`.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using rbenv and homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes ; brew install apple-gcc42
```

Comment: I also needed to do `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: I'm not using rbenv, but I had to uninstall and reinstall apple-gcc42, probably cuz I had it before upgrading to mavericks

```shell
brew uninstall apple-gcc42;
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Answer (score 2):

Because i am sure i will land here again.

My issue was that `sudo xcodebuild -license` does nothing actually and i had to manually start xcode to agree to their terms to get it working. What a glorious OS.

Comment: Yep, that was it for me too. how spectacularly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the following error during "bundle install":

---

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@storefront/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@storefront/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

---

After updating Xcode and installing CLT, doing the following took care of the issue:

```
bundle clean --force

bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the latest Xcode and Command Line Tools (inside Xcode).
It's obviously something with your Xcode or PATH. What does `which clang` give?

Comment: It gives `/usr/bin/clang`. I have the latest Xcode and Command Line Tools already installed. I'm willing to accept that something may have gotten wrong with the configuration, but I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode and CLT multiple times and this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Can you try compiling Ruby yourself from source (without rvm)? Perhaps it will shed some light on what the real problem is...

Answer (score 0):

I can't repeat enough how frustrating it was for me when I had the SAME issue on Mountain Lion. I ultimately upgraded my OS to Mavericks after I read that there were some GCC issues with Mountain Lion. I still had the same error :/

The ONLY thing that worked was reinstalling ruby after installing the command line tools.

"For future visitors, this worked for me. Not that it should matter but I installed rvm with brew. Xcode and Xcode CLT was already installed. I simply had to (no sudo throughout any of this) rvm use 2.0.0, then xcode -license, agree to the license then rvm reinstall 2.0.0. last step very important, indeed"

Then $ gem install rails

This fixed my issues perfectly. This blog gives a great walkthrough with screenshots on how to install Mac Development Tools (Command Line Tools) multiple ways (http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Centos and Fedora.

> You have to install development tools first.

which should be installed with

```
dnf install @development-tools
```

For more info see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35303883/9003945

Answer (score 0):

in my case, when i open the `mkmf.log` file, i see the error is 'ruby/config.h' file not found. so i install another ruby using brew, `brew install ruby`, and then set the `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `~/.zshrc` like this.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

finally execute gem install agin，it's success.

Comment: While this worked for you, this is a very old question and related to the specific version that he wanted to install. installing a different version is at best a "work around" not a fix, since it doesn't install the specific version he was looking at