# Error running Jekyll on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: ruby, xcode, jekyll

I have a problem running Jekyll on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. When I run `jekyll serve`, I get the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro-Svetlana:iloveip svetlana$ jekyll serve
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 22 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
MacBook-Pro-Svetlana:iloveip svetlana$
```

I had to reinstall OS X Yosemite. And I might have done something wrong. First, I installed Xcode Command Line Tools without actually installing Xcode. Then I followed instructions on [this site](http://installrails.com) to install Ruby and Git. After that I installed Jekyll but it wasn't running with `jekyll serve`. So I installed Xcode, but still got some errors.

So I upgraded RVM, and also upgraded Ruby to 2.2.3. After that I uninstalled and installed Jekyll once again. But when I try to run it I get the error above.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Update Ruby and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279856/the-compiler-failed-to-generate-an-executable-file-runtimeerror

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador, thank you very much. Now Jekyll has installed, but it's not running. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. New problem seems that you have a problem with gem sources.

Re-generating sources can help.

```
$ gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
$ gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
$ gem install jekyll
```

And now, install Jekyll again.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Do I need to do it in my Jekyll folder or in the default destination when I open the terminal?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! But now I get a different error. I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677409/error-when-running-jekyll-cannot-load-such-file-google-api-client-loaderror