# How to fix an error installing Rails on Fedora

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fedora-23

I am a newcomer to Fedora and Rails and do not know how to solve this problem.  Here is the error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160209-8980-yntffh.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
  --help
  --clean
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
  from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
  from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
  from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
  from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
  from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
  from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
  from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
  from extconf.rb:336:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2):

The key message here is

> You have to install development tools first.

which should be installed with

```
dnf install @development-tools
```

See "[What is the Fedora equivalent of the Debian build-essential package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259039)" for more information.

Comment: did not help
`//6.@firepic.@org/6/images/2016-02/10/zaz1i7xdymqc.png` Delete '@')))