# rvm install 1.9.3 failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I tried reinstalling ruby, xcode, and a bunch of other things because I kept getting these strange C compiler errors. At some point all my rubies were uninstalled so I started back at the beginning...

```
rvm get head && rvm reload
rvm install 1.9.3
```

I get the following error:

```
No binary rubies available for: downloads/ruby-1.9.3-p327.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracted to /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

In **configure.log** I see:

```
[2012-11-14 13:21:54] env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

And in **config.log** I see:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Mattans-MacBook-Air.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.2.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 144 tasks, 704 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 2.79, Mach factor: 1.19
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/usr/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails328/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
PATH: /Users/mgriffel/.rvm/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/sm/bin
PATH: /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
PATH: /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2769: checking build system type
configure:2783: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
configure:2851: checking host system type
configure:2864: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
configure:2884: checking target system type
configure:2897: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
configure:3378: checking for C compiler version
configure:3387: /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin12-gcc-apple-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3) (MacPorts apple-gcc42 5666.3_9)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3387: /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin12
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_apple-gcc42/apple-gcc42/work/objroot/src/configure --disable-checking --prefix=/opt/local --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --libexecdir=/opt/local/libexec/apple-gcc42 --libdir=/opt/local/lib/apple-gcc42 --includedir=/opt/local/include/apple-gcc42 --program-suffix=-apple-4.2 --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --enable-werror-always --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin12- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --target=i686-apple-darwin12 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3) (MacPorts apple-gcc42 5666.3_9)
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3387: /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 -V >&5
gcc-apple-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:3398: $? = 1
configure:3387: /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 -qversion >&5
i686-apple-darwin12-gcc-apple-4.2.1: no input files
configure:3398: $? = 1
configure:3418: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3440: /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2   -L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include conftest.c  >&5
i686-apple-darwin12-gcc-apple-4.2.1: CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin12-gcc-apple-4.2.1: CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include: No such file or directory
configure:3444: $? = 1
configure:3482: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3487: error: in `/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327':
configure:3489: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
ac_cv_prog_CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS='-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include'
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2012-11-10'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin12.2.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin12.2.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/mgriffel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin12.2.0'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong and I've been stuck here for days. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have the latest version of Xcode and CLT installed.

Comment: Are xcode and ruby related in this problem? what are you trying to do that involves ruby and xcode? when did the problem start?

Comment: Yes Ali I'm installing ruby, and the problem happened once I updated Xcode and the Command Line Tools. Louiscoquio, that's a good point. I should go back and pick an answer for each question!

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this?  It looks like your compiler is coming from macports rather than xcode/CLT. I don't use macports so I can't confirm your problem.  Perhaps you can temporarily move your macports /opt/local out of your path to see if using the system compiler helps.

Comment: Yes I resolved the problem. See below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in RailsInstaller OSX 1.0.3 - (Found that out while reading [Problems installing Ruby on Mountain Lion - ruby 1.9.3 wont' compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928581/problems-installing-ruby-on-mountain-lion-ruby-1-9-3-wont-compile))

I needed to change `/etc/rvmrc` to contain this:

```
umask g+w
export -a rvm_configure_env
rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

For more info see: https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix/issues/10

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for posting this answer. I spent few hours last evening trying unsuccessfully everything mentioned on every other forum/blog/question and called it a night. This morning yours is the first post I followed and now I not only have 1.9.3 but also 2.0.0. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To get ruby to compile on my mac which is using Mountain Lion and xcode 4.5.2, I have to create a soft link from gcc-4.2 to gcc somewhere on my path.  I originally found the suggestion on this page: https://gist.github.com/1860902

Perhaps it will help you:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

If it doesn't help, you can remove it:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Good luck!

Comment: Looks like when I install OSX Maverick and XCode 5 it changed the gcc name somehow. Thanks for posting as I spent 2 hours today trying to solve this nightmarish issue.

Answer (score 0):

mattangriffel's solution did it for me. In my case, my third line was nearly identical but where he had

```
    rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

I had

```
    rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

Fixing mine to look like his did the trick.