# rvm install configuration error mac os x lion

Tags: installation, osx-lion, rvm, configure

My rvm can't install anything due to configure error:

```
configure:3489: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Looking at `config.log`, I see:

```
ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/davidholmgren/.rvm/usr/lib'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
```

It appears configure is blowing the parsing of the flags variables, but this happens for any rvm install, so I suspect the problem is not in `configure.in` but in rvm's invocation, but `config.log` says

```
It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/davidholmgren/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Found fix (edit /etc/rvmrc) at [rvm install 1.9.3 failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385273/rvm-install-1-9-3-failing?rq=1)

Thanks!