# Errors installing Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3-p385 on my work machine using Mountain Lion.

I've installed RVM and run

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

But I get this error...

```
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr --disable-shared', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

This is the contents of configure.log that the error points to...

```
[2013-02-18 10:10:50] ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

It's all a bit cryptic to me. If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing Ruby with RVM (OSX 10.8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072524/error-installing-ruby-with-rvm-osx-10-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problem with railsinstaller default settings, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12929017/497756

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14662569/1008938) question and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663025/1008938).

To sum up, install MacPorts and run:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install gcc-apple42
CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --without-tk --without-tcl
```

Comment: I use homebrew, but have used that to install gcc-apple42. But... still getting same errors :(

Comment: that's different problem, it's because of /etc/rvmrc installed by RailsInstaller - it has bug in quoting environment, btw. would you be interested in adding automated support for MacPorts in RVM? => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/1544

Comment: @markstewie: Change `/opt/local` to `/usr/local`. then remove your downvote.

Comment: Sorry @Linuxios didn't mean to downvote.. anyhow changed to CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --enable-shared --without-tk --without-tcl and still get the same error.

Comment: it does not help because it's not the fix,, here is the proper fix http://stackoverflow.com/a/12929017/497756